# Does there exist a square whose vertices have distances 1,2,3,4 from an arbitrary line

Tags: geometry

I'm working on this problem and it seems like the solution is super obvious but I can't find any except looking at triangles sharing the same side

Answer (score 5):

What about $(0,1),(-1,3),(1,4),(2,2)$? Those vertices have distance 1,3,4,2 to the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 2):

If the vertices of a square are some prescribed distances from a given line, then (by rotating a quarter-turn about the square's center) its vertices are also the same prescribed distances (in a different order) from some *perpendicular* line.

[image]

So, the distances effectively give *coordinates* of the vertices relative to the "axes" comprising the two lines.

From the image, we can take the coordinates arising from distances $1, 2, 3, 4$ to be $A=(1,3)$, $B=(2,1)$, $C=(4,2)$, $D=(3,4)$. Verifying that these correspond to vertices of a square is a straightforward exercise left to the reader. $\square$

---

A nice little follow-up exercise is to generalize: Replace $1, 2, 3, 4$ with, say, $p_1<p_2<p_3<p_4$, and determine condition(s) on the $p_i$ such that there's a square whose vertices are those distances from an arbitrary line.

Comment: You should propose this follow up exercise as a question...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean? you should be able to calculate the angle of the square from the $\tan^{-1}(s/(s/2))$

[Image of the square](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUF6n.png)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

One side should climb 1 unit when travelling 2 units parallel to x-axis reference taken. The y-coordinates should be in steps of $( 1,2,4,3)$ for diagonal points to compensate. Must be rotatable around square center for symmetry of vertices.

The slopes should be

$$ \tan^{-1}\frac{1}{2},\,\tan^{-1}(-2);$$

Radius $ \sqrt{\dfrac {5}{2}}$ and  square side $ \sqrt 5$

Lowest point

$$(0,1)$$

Vertices $(A,B,C,D)$ and center $ \left(\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{5}{2}\right); $

Symmetric squares reflected about y-axis or x-axis are also admissible.

Answer (score 0):

You can assume that the arbitrary line is the $x$ axis.  The center of the square can be taken as the point $(0, y_0)$.

Assuming the square lies totally in the upper half plane, then $y_0$ can be found immediately as the average of the distances.  Thus $y_0$ is $\frac{1}{4} (1 + 2 + 3 + 4) = 2.5$.

Further, if the unknown side of the square is $a$ and the tilt angle of one of the two diagonals is $\theta$ then from a small sketch of the square, one deduces that

$ a \sqrt{2} \sin \theta = 3 - 2 = 1 $

And

$ a \sqrt{2} \cos \theta = 4 - 1 = 3 $

Thus $\tan \theta = \dfrac{1}{3} $, so that,
$\sin \theta = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}} , \cos \theta = \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10} }$

Hence, $a = \dfrac{\sqrt{10}}{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{5} $

Now everything is complete.  So we can calculate the four vertices of the square:

$\begin{equation} \begin{split}
A &= (0, 2.5) - \sqrt{\dfrac{5}{2}} ( \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10} } , \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}} ) \\
&=  (- \dfrac{3}{2} , 2 ) \end{split} \end{equation}$

Similarly,

$\begin{equation} \begin{split}
C &= (0, 2.5) + \sqrt{\dfrac{5}{2}} ( \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10} } , \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10}} ) \\
&=  ( \dfrac{3}{2} , 3 ) \end{split} \end{equation}$

and,

$\begin{equation} \begin{split}
C &= (0, 2.5) + \sqrt{\dfrac{5}{2}} ( \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10} } , -\dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10}} ) \\
&=  ( \dfrac{1}{2} , 1 ) \end{split} \end{equation}$

$\begin{equation} \begin{split}
D &= (0, 2.5) + \sqrt{\dfrac{5}{2}} ( -\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{10} } , \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{10}} ) \\
&=  ( -\dfrac{1}{2} , 4 ) \end{split} \end{equation}$